# Strategy pattern

Tags: java, grails, design-patterns, groovy

I have to implement API for different clients. Implementation for each client will be different. So, I am thinking of using a strategy pattern in groovy(similar to Java) where I will have an interface and for each client I will create a class(which implements an interface) and I want to configure the class to be called using UI(dropdown selection for class) through an interface.

```
interface PricingStrategy {


}



class CanadaPricingStrategy implements PricingStrategy {

  Method 1...
  Method 2...

}

class BrazilPricingStrategy implements PricingStrategy {

  Method 1...
  Method 2...

}
```

Would it be the best way to do that or I can use pluggable-behaviour approach by using closure as a variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be the best way to do that or I can use pluggable-behaviour
>   approach by using closure as a variable ?

It is impossible to say for sure without knowing more about the requirements but in general the interface based approach that you described will make sense.  That can still be pluggable.  You could do something like have a separate plugin for each implementation and different versions of the app can be built with different plugins that provide different behavior.  You could use a dynamic discover mechanism that loads up all of the `PricingStrategy` implementations that are on the class path.  You have a lot of options but with almost no information about your requirements I would say that the interface based approach is a solid starting point.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am thinking of providing user(Admin) with an option to configure strategy for each client. It will be a dropdown containing list of PricingStrategy implementations. The strategy will be used/called based on the configuration done for each client(class name stored in DB). But  I think it is a more java-oriented approach. I am using groovy so was thinking of a more better way(without using interface).

Comment: " I am using groovy so was thinking of a more better way(without using interface)." - You can eliminate the interface and take advantage of Groovy dynamic dispatch, but I wouldn't do that.  The interface is valuable for a number of reasons, even with Groovy.  For example, in Grails we use interfaces in many places where we want applications or plugins to contribute behavior to the core framework.  It is a very common approach.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with this approach then. I will get back to you in case I have any questions.

Comment: Also, in this case I will not  be able to use services(which we use in Grails), as it will be a simple groovy class implementing an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I will divide your problem statement into two parts based on sentences mentioned below:

1. To implement APIs for different clients.
2. And, Implementation for each client will be different.

As per two points I will suggest you to implement your problem statements using two different design patterns:

1. **Adapter Design Pattern**: API should be always designed by using Adapter design pattern because source and client interfaces can be incompatible and this design pattern converts the incompatible interface into another interface that client requires.
   This type case always happens in the design of API due to several circumstances like different kinds of technology, parameters, etc. at both sides.
2. **Strategy Design Pattern**: Internal Logical implementation of different clients are different. So, you should design this with the help of strategy pattern.

And, call this strategy pattern into Adapter Design pattern.